# How can I find the mistake in the below code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

**PROBLEM DESCRIPTION:** Sanjay has `m` rupees, each chocolate costs `c` rupees, the shopkeeper will give away `k` chocolates for `w` wrappers. Can you find now how many chocolates Sanjay will be able to eat?

**INPUT:** 4 integers separated by space in order `m`, `c`, `w`, `k` by condition

- `c,w > 0`
- `m, k >= 0`
- `k < w`

**OUTPUT:** An integer denoting the number of chocolates Sanjay will be able to get.

---

**Sample 1**

**INPUT:** 15, 2, 3, 1

**OUTPUT:** 10

**EXPLANATION:**

- Sanjay has 15 rupees, buys 7 chocolates for 2 rupees each.
- Sanjay now has 7 wrappers, exchanges 6 of them for 2 more chocolates.
- Sanjay now has 3 wrappers and exchanges them for 1 more chocolate making a total of 10 chocolates

---

**Sample 2**

**INPUT:** 15, 2, 3, 2

**OUTPUT:** 17

**EXPLANATION:**

- Sanjay has 15 rupees, buys 7 chocolates for 2 rupees each.
- Sanjay now has 7 wrappers, exchanges 6 of them for 4 more chocolates.
- Sanjay now has 5 wrappers and exchanges 3 of them for 2 more chocolates.
- Sanjay now has 4 wrappers and exchanges 3 of them for 2 more chocolates.
- Sanjay now has 3 wrappers and exchanges them for 2 chocolates making a total of 17 chocolates.

---

I tried the below code but getting the wrong answer.

```py
    n = input()
    i = n.split(',')
    m = int(i[0])
    c = int(i[1])
    w = m//c
    choc = m//c

    while(w//3!=0):
        choc = choc + (w//3)
        w = (w//3) + (w%3)
    print(choc)
```

What am I doing wrong in the code?

Comment: Please update your question with actual input and output and the expected output.

Comment: Note that an ideal Stack Overflow question is specific and narrow -- the idea is to be a huge FAQ. If your question is "why does the standard-library function X return the value when I expect the value Y?", that's likely to be a good question, because other people might have the same problem with standard-library function X. If it's "why does this big bunch of logic do the wrong thing?", that's likely to be a *bad* question, because nobody else will have that same big bunch of logic, and even if someone did, how would they find the exact question where it was previously asked?

Comment: ...thus, we want people to narrow down the *component* of that logic that isn't doing what they expect and ask only about that, in such a way as to let someone else having the same problem potentially be able to find and learn from that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you trade in w wrappers, you get k chocolates back, but you've not included this in your code.
I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with the modulo either.

Here's a version that works for at least your sample inputs.

```
n = input()
i = n.split(',')
m, c, w, k = [int(x) for x in i]

total_eaten = 0
current_money = m

# buy as many as we can
buy = current_money // c

# reduce money, increase eaten
current_money -= buy * c
total_eaten += buy

# then start trading wrappers

wrappers = total_eaten

while True:
  # we get extra chocolate for wrappers back
  extra_choc = (wrappers // w)

  # remove the wrappers
  wrappers -= extra_choc * w

  if extra_choc == 0:
    # no more extra chocolate :(
    break

  # eat the extra chocolate
  total_eaten += extra_choc * k

  # and also increase how many wrappers we have
  wrappers += extra_choc * k

print(total_eaten)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
number = input()
myList = number.split(',')
m = int(myList[0])
c = int(myList[1])
k= int(myList[3])
w = m//c
chocolate = m//c
#start writing your code here
while w//3 !=0 :
    wrapper = (w//3)*k
    chocolate = chocolate + wrapper
    w= wrapper +w%3
print(chocolate)
```

And make it more general case:

```
#take input here
import ast
input_str = input()
input_list = ast.literal_eval(input_str)
m = int(input_list[0])  # money
c = int(input_list[1])  # chocolates
n = int(input_list[2])  # wrappers to exchange
k = int(input_list[3])  # how many chocolates one gets for exchanging 'n' wrappers

choc = m//c        # how many chocolate one can buy initially out of total money 'm', given the price of chocolate 'c'
w = m//c           # same will be the number of wrappers initially     

while (w//n!=0):
  wrap = (w//n)*k
  choc = choc + wrap
  w = wrap + w%n

print(choc)
```

Then give any input such as:

```
15, 2, 3, 2
15, 2, 4, 1
15, 3, 2, 1
```

You still get the right answers.